# Prove or disprove $f \in O(g)$, with $f=5^{\log(n)^2}$ and $g = n^{\log(n)}$

Tags: asymptotics

I have a feeling $f$ grows faster than $g$, and therefore it is not the case that $f \in O(g)$, but no matter how much I try, I do not see how to prove it.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I am assuming all logarithms are in base $2$, but the conclusion wouldn't change if the $\log$ was the natural one.*

So, you have
$$
f(n) = 5^{\log(n)^2} = 2^{\log(5)\cdot\log(n)^2}
$$
while
$$
g(n) = n^{\log(n)} = 2^{\log(n)\cdot\log(n)} = 2^{\log(n)^2}
$$

Therefore,
$$
\frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = 2^{\log(5)\cdot\log(n)^2 - \log(n)^2} = 2^{(\log 5 - 1)\log(n)^2} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \infty
$$
since $\log 5 -1 > 0$. Can you conclude?

Comment: But the bases do matter though. If you were taking base 4 (say) i.e., $\log n \doteq \log_4 n$, then $n^{\log n} = 2^{2 \log n \cdot \log n}$ and not $2^{\log n \cdot \log n}$ as you wrote above.

Comment: Yes (as the last line says, it relies on $\log 5 > 1$). When I said "the conclusion wouldn't change", it's because I assumed the base would be either $2$ (binary, standard for these computer-science-type exercises) or $e$ (natural). *Nobody* would consider $\log_{17}$ and just write it $\log$ (base 10 in the option, of course, but it seems highly unlikely to me, again). @Mike

Comment: Indeed no one takes base 17 but working base 10 is definitely not unheard of even in CS. I could see someone reading what you wrote and assuming that it would hold if we were working base 10

Comment: @Mike Fair, I edited the first sentence to mention base 2 *or base $e$*.

Comment: Yes, I think now I can conclude. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The base that you take the logs do matter. For example on the one hand let's assume that the base is much bigger than 5; e.g, for example $\log n \doteq \log_{125} n$:

$$5^{\log^2_{125} n} = (5^{\log_{125} n})^{\log_{125} n} = (n^{\frac{1}{3}})^{\log_{125} n} = (n^{\log_{125} n})^{\frac{1}{3}}  = g^{\frac{1}{3}}.$$

On the other hand let us now assume that the base is $2<5$  e.g, for example $\log n \doteq \log_{2} n$:

$$5^{\log^2_2 n} > 4^{\log^2_2 n} = (4^{\log_2 n})^{\log_2 n} = (n^2)^{\log_2 n} = (n^{\log_2 n})^2 =  g^2.$$

So can you conclude for yourself the following: Iff the base is 5 or greater (e.g., 10) then $f \in O(g)$. If the base is less than 5 (i.e., 2 or $e$) then $f \not \in O(g)$.